# execute sql statements in java at runtime using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, sql, runtime, execute

In the below code while loop is not running. Can someone suggest me what is going wrong with this code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class A 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int value = 0;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM A2A_TP_INFO";
        String filename="file.txt";
        String filepath="/home/mit"+"export/file.txt";
        String exportQuery = "/home/mit/JavaProj/proj/export/query";
        String cmd[] = {
            "/bin/ksh",
            "-c",
            "" + exportQuery + " " +filepath+ "   \""
            + sql + ";\" " 
        };

        try {
            //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            Process p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sql);
            // p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p1.getInputStream())); 

            while ((value = input.read()) != -1) {
                char c = (char) value;
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. What is the question? 2. What is the error? : O

Comment: Don't use Runtime.exec(), use a `ProcessBuilder`!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an intermediary shell. And use a `ProcessBuilder`:

```
final List<String> fullCommand = Arrays.asList(exportQuery, filePath, sql + ';')
final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(fullCommand);
final Process p = builder.start();
```

Note that using `ProcessBuilder` you can send stdout/stderr to a file, and even customize stdin. You can set the working directory, customize the environment etc. Use that. Really. Runtime.exec() has no reason to be used anymore.

Comment: asList() is taking only 1 parameter and there i am putting cmd but the result is still same its not getting inside while loop.

Comment: Uh, no, asList() can take many parameters. It is a varargs method!

Comment: As to "not getting in while loop", don't do that with a `ProcessBuilder`. Redirect stdout/stderr to a file and read from that file afterwards. See the javadoc.